# Adjusting in longitudinal data?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, panel-data

I am slightly confused on what tests should be used to do a multivariate analysis for longitudinal data.

I've got data of two surveys done on the same sample, a year apart. The outcome measured is whether the person is smoking - yes/no.

Essentially, it's got a bunch of variables in wide format like this:

ID VAR1_w1 VAR1_w2 VAR3_w1 VAR3_w2.... + baselines

I've got descriptives (McNemar's, paired t-test etc.) done, but am stuck on the further analysis.

What models can I use to adjust for a) the repeated measures and b) the effect of other variables in the data?

Comment: You should take a look at fixed effects models

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any reason for fixed vs mixed though?